# how does "System.out.println" work in JS?... :)

Tags: javascript

My background is in java and right now Im getting into learning Javascript. (I'm porting this java code that I made into javascript but it behaves a bit different than I expected?? If I use "console.log()" instead of "document.write" I'm NOT getting the same result..why?

thanks 4 yr time! Some insight will be very appreciated!

```
var counter = 1;    

function println(str) {

    console.log(str);//

}   

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

  for (var j = i; j < 5; j++) {

       document.write("#");
// println("#"); 


  }

  for (var k = 1; k <= counter; k++) {

    document.write("*");
// println("*"); 

  }

  document.write("<br/>");
//println(" "); <--- "\n" ? 

  counter+= 2; //
} // ends application
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for document.write and console.log?  They're unrelated.

Comment: If you want to learn JavaScript, forget ANYTHING related to Java. They are two completely different languages. Stop this "how to make language X to work like language Y".

Comment: "Not the same result" means what?

Comment: @epascarello well I found out that u dont have system.out.print in js..so u have to add everything in the same string. like string+= and then at the end of the first loop u make the println with console.log....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write()` is for printing content to the page of your document, while `console.log()` is used predominantly for diagnostic/debug information to be emitted in the console of your web browser. Specifically, `document.write()` is intended to be consumed by the viewer of your page, while `console.log()` is generally not.

Comment: but how can I achieve the same result in the console window...?

Comment: If you'd like to log to both, then you'd need to call both.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log logs stuff into browser console. Install Firebug (getfirebug.com) and you will see your logs.

Also there is nice description about how it works http://getfirebug.com/logging.

Also, using document.write is not really elegant, you can use it only on page load, and it's blocking whole page. You basically should not use it at all. If you try to use document.write after page is loaded, it will replace whole content of your document with your last "log".

Comment: Or use the built-in JavaScript console found in most browsers.

Comment: Like, I'm guessing you're using IE. This will do to :).